# Azure-search document count issue

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We are using azure-search and are experiencing some strange issues.  We have two environments (internal production and external production), both of which have their own separate index (IndexInternal and IndexExternal).

I am using the Red Dog search portal to check the document size and count (https://github.com/reddog-io/RedDog.Search.Portal).

What I have experienced is this:

- Re-indexed internal production site and there are 14500 documents
- Re-indexed external production site and there are 14500 documents

After 3/4 days I have checked the indexes and the count seem to have changed drastically:

- Internal production site now has 24500 documents
- External production site now has 24500 documents

When I query the indexes there doesn't seem to be anything unusual in there.

There is no way that 10000 documents have been pushed up since the re-index of the sites.

Has anyone any idea as to what could be happening here?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 2):

The count that is shown from Azure Search is not updated real-time.  Is it possible that you looked at the count soon after the documents and we are showing you this count based on the current numbers we have?  Also, please remember that it also takes some time for your data to become searchable after you index the documents.

Liam

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks for getting back to me.  Well, the first count (14500) is correct as my code records how many records are due to go up to index.  I just don't understand how this can change by 10000 records after 3 days?  Even when I checked after 24 hours, the count was still correct.  For this to happen on both indexes too is just too much of a coincidence.

Comment: One thing to also mention here is that one of the columns is very large (it basically stores WYSIWYG content).  Could it be that azure fragments each (large) record after a period of time so that it improves performance?

Comment: Hi Adam,
Have you tried looking at the count on the Azure Preview Portal, or by using the [$count REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798924.aspx)?